# Выбор максимального элемента по строке SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть следующие [данные](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4c205/1/0) :

```
Type    Max1    Max2    Max3
A   3   5   NULL
B   57  52  Null
C   7   8   10
D   NULL    NULL    5
```

Необходимо посчитать максимум из трех столбцов по каждой строке и записать это в столбец `Max`

То есть на выходе должны получить нечто такое:

```
Type    Max
A   5
B   57
C   10
D   5
```

Есть ли какая то функция которая считает максимум в строке ? Или каким иным методом можно это сделать?

Пишется в MS SQL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6871572/8324991 ну и там другие ответы, если этот не подойдёт

Comment: *Есть ли какая то функция которая считает максимум в строке ?* Нет, однородные данные в разных полях - это денормализация, для такой фигни никто ничего писать не станет. Руками... два вложенных CASE.

Comment: > "для такой фигни никто ничего писать не станет."

И, тем не менее, такая фигня есть даже в T-SQL, только для Azure - функция GREATEST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать обычный `MAX` вместе с [Values Table Constructor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
select Type,
   (select max(val) from (values (max1), (max2), (max3)) v(val))
from mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Type, GREATEST(Max1, Max2, Max3) AS Max From ...
```

Comment: ```'GREATEST' is not a recognized built-in function name``` в MS SQL

Comment: Weird. And what is your MS SQL server?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016